# Write pattern for the page from file in the my extension dirrectory

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am trying to make simply Firefox WebExtensions, which will open my html page and execute some scripts on it.
As i understand when i want to use scripts on the page i must declare content_scripts in manifest.json file and make pattern for page address.
How can i write pattern for the page from file "table.html" in the my extension directory?
This is my code for start this page:
**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "LightDials",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Something",
  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/LightDials_48.png",
    "96": "icons/LightDials_96.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "alarms",
    //"background",
    "bookmarks",
    "browserSettings",
    "browsingData",
    //"contentSettings",
    "contextMenus",
    "contextualIdentities",
    "cookies",
    //"debugger",
    "downloads",
    "downloads.open",
    "find",
    "geolocation",
    "history",
    "identity",
    "idle",
    "management",
    "menus",
    "nativeMessaging",
    "notifications",
    //"pageCapture",
    "pkcs11",
    "privacy",
    "proxy",
    "sessions",
    "storage",
    "tabs",
    "theme",
    "topSites",
    "webNavigation",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": [ "background.js" ]
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://table.html/*"],
      "js": [ "page-eater.js" ]
    }
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/LightDials_32.png",
    "default_title": "LightDials"
  },
  "applications": {
    "gecko": {
      "id": "kloshar13@yahoo.com",
      "strict_min_version": "45.0"
    }
  },
}
```

**background.js**

```
    function openPage() {
        browser.tabs.update({
            url: "table.html"
        });
    }
    browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(openPage);
```

Comment: You will probably need to use ./table.html. As for the match pattern, I would omit /* and try again.

Comment: @Smile4ever I have error in both cases. There was an error during installation: Extension is invalid. Maybe u have another variant?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply edit table.html and include a script tag:

```
<script src="relative/path/filename.js"></script>
```

Comment: It works. But i need a execute script from onclick event like this:  <img src="images/1.png" onclick='showAlert()' />. How can i do it?

Comment: Assuming your HTML is <img src="images/1.png" id="firstImage" /> you can use document.getElementById("firstImage").addEventListener("click", function(){ console.log("do something"); });

Comment: As i understand i must write this code in my script file. In the table.html i have <script src="alert.js"></script> and <img id="firstImage" src="1.png"/>. In alert.js i have document.getElementById("firstImage").addEventListener("click", function(){ console.log("do something"); }); Console gives me on page load: 'TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null'. Source - "alert.js"... Sorry if i tangle you (and myself)!

Comment: Are you sure you didn't make a typo with "firstImage"?

Comment: no, i use copy and paste. I note strange thing: console write error when page is loaded, but if i input "document.getElementById("firstImage").addEventListener("click", function () { console.log("do something"); });" in console i can click on image once for print "do something"! It works only once after command...

Comment: Did you load your script on the bottom of the page so it loads last?

Comment: **@Smile4ever, thanks a lot!** it work! I didn't think the order of script  executing is important. You are help me!